# react-bootstrap grid layout columns rendering as rows

Tags: react-bootstrap

I have the following render method and I am expecting to have two columns in my layout but am getting two rows instead:

```
  render() {
return (
    <div>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/latest/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/latest/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" />
        <Grid>
            <Row>
                <Col>
                    My Header
                </Col>
            </Row>
            <Row>
                <Col>test</Col><Col>test</Col>
            </Row>
        </Grid>
  </div>
);
```

I'd expect things to render like this:

```
My header

Col One Col Two
```

but instead things are rendered like this:

```
My header

Col One

Col Two
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

You are likely not importing the bootstrap css. Check out [this](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/issues/1684) issue on Github or the documentation on [this](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction/) page for React Bootstrap.

From React Bootstrap Website:

> Because React-Bootstrap doesn't depend on a very precise version of Bootstrap, we don't ship with any included css. However, some stylesheet is required to use these components. How and which bootstrap styles you include is up to you, but the simplest way is to include the latest styles from the CDN.

```
<link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
  integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T"
  crossorigin="anonymous"
  />
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I resolved it by adding xs- specifications. Not entirely sure why it fixed it, so can't really elaborate on that. Maybe someone more experienced can.

To clarify, here's a working example of your code:

```
render() {
return (
    <div>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/latest/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/latest/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" />
        <Grid>
            <Row>
                <Col>
                    My Header
                </Col>
            </Row>
            <Row>
                <Col xs = "5" >test</Col><Col xs = "5" >test</Col>
            </Row>
        </Grid>
  </div>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

TRY this code

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      1 of 2
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      2 of 2
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      1 of 3
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      2 of 3
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      3 of 3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

For more info :
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but that produced a similar output. Do you have a suggestion using react-bootstrap's Grid component? That is what I'm really trying to leverage.

Comment: I also tried using the container class on my div and it didn't change anything.