# Bootstrap columns appearing like Rows

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, bootstrap-4

My container code where I'm holding my columns

```
 <Container>
        <Row style={{backgroundColor:'red'}}>
          <Col style={{backgroundColor: 'cyan'}}>1 of 3</Col>
          <Col xs={6}>2 of 3 (wider)</Col>
          <Col>3 of 3</Col>
        </Row>
      </Container>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [react-bootstrap grid layout columns rendering as rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46017728/react-bootstrap-grid-layout-columns-rendering-as-rows)

Comment: Thanks man.. I figured it out just now !